# jQuery .each() - Getting the text of array values

Tags: jquery

I've got stuck in a small piece of code. The setup is something like this -

```
<span class="span1">Something here</span>
<div><h3>Required Text</h3></div>
<span class="span2">Something here</span>
<div><h3>Required Text</h3></div>
<span class="span3">Something here</span>
<div><h3>Required Text</h3></div>
<span class="span4">Something here</span>
<div><h3>Required Text</h3></div>
<span class="span5">Something here</span>
<div><h3>Required Text</h3></div>

$(document).ready(function () { 
        var appendLblarr = [".span1", ".span2", ".span3", ".span4", ".span5"];            
        $.each(appendLblarr, function (i, val) {
            var appendLabel = $(".span1 + div h3").text();
            jQuery(val).mouseover(function(){
                //alert();
                $(this).append("<div class='appendedTT'><p>" + appendLabel + "</p></div>");  
            })

            .mouseout(function() {
                $( ".appendedTT" ).remove();
            });
      });      
});
```

In the variable `appendLabel`, I'm trying to get the text of the `<h3>` which is in a `<div>` next to a `<span>`

The question is, how do i put that in a loop.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I'm trying to get the text that is inside the `<h3>` into the `appendedTT` `<div>`

Comment: Oh, I see what you're trying to do.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - each in its own. I'm basically appending a tooltip onhover.

Comment: My question is, if i can use `var appendLabel = $(appendLblarr  + "div h3").text();` or what is the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a loop for this:

```
$(".span1, .span2, .span3, .span4, .span5")
.on("mouseover", function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var tt = $("<div class=appendedTT></div>");
  tt.text($this.next("div").find("h3").text());
  $this.append(tt);
})
.on("mouseout", function() {
  $(this).find(".appendedTT").remove();
});
```

That selects the five spans and sets up the `mouseover` and `mouseout` handlers. Within the `mouseover` handler, we go from `this` to the next element (which must be a `div`) and then into the `h3` within it, grab the text, and then use that to append a `.appendedTT` element. Mouseout removes it.

Live copy:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".span1, .span2, .span3, .span4, .span5")
    .on("mouseover", function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var tt = $("<div class=appendedTT></div>");
      tt.text($this.next("div").find("h3").text());
      $this.append(tt);
    })
    .on("mouseout", function() {
      $(this).find(".appendedTT").remove();
    });
});
```

```html
<span class="span1">Something here</span>
<div><h3>Required Text 1</h3></div>
<span class="span2">Something here</span>
<div><h3>Required Text 2</h3></div>
<span class="span3">Something here</span>
<div><h3>Required Text 3</h3></div>
<span class="span4">Something here</span>
<div><h3>Required Text 4</h3></div>
<span class="span5">Something here</span>
<div><h3>Required Text 5</h3></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you're into that sort of thing, the `mouseover` could be a one-liner:

```
$(this).append($("<div class=appendedTT></div>").text($(this).next("div").find("h3").text()));
```

I find one-liners like that harder to read and debug, though.

Comment: Thank you. I used the one-liner instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$(val)` the same way you did to set event handlers to get the following div, with `$(val).next().find("h3")` or `$(val).next("div").find("h3")` if you want to explicitly restrict to a div (NOTE that second solution will return an empty selection if next element is not a div, it won't try to see following elements until it finds a div)

```js
$(document).ready(function () { 
        var appendLblarr = [".span1", ".span2", ".span3", ".span4", ".span5"];            
        $.each(appendLblarr, function (i, val) {
            var appendLabel = $(val).next().find("h3").text();
            $(val).mouseover(function(){
                //alert();
                $(this).append("<div class='appendedTT'><p>" + appendLabel + "</p></div>");  
            })

            .mouseout(function() {
                $( ".appendedTT" ).remove();
            });
      });      
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="span1">Something here</span>
<div><h3>Required Text 1</h3></div>
<span class="span2">Something here</span>
<div><h3>Required Text 2</h3></div>
<span class="span3">Something here</span>
<div><h3>Required Text 3</h3></div>
<span class="span4">Something here</span>
<div><h3>Required Text 4</h3></div>
<span class="span5">Something here</span>
<div><h3>Required Text 5</h3></div>
```